# SQL and DataTables Returning Values for the Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datatable

Now before I ask I KNOW this is WAY OVER MY HEAD!  I have no idea how to even begin editing this code.  I have been DUMPED in it by some people I was working with and have been left to finish a project by myself!  I have the code below and I would like to add in there

```
AND WHERE fieldname IS NOT NULL
```

Now for the original code where it needs to be added!

```
$sWhere = "";
if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
{
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ')';
}

/* Individual column filtering */
for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
{
    if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
    {
        if ( $sWhere == "" )
        {
            $sWhere = "WHERE ";
        }
        else
        {
            $sWhere .= " AND ";
        }
        $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
    }
}
```

I have NO IDEA where to even start.  I hope someone can help, thanks in advance for baring with me!

**///////// UPDATE   /   UPDATE   /   UPDATE   /   UPDATE   /   UPDATE/////////**

Ok so I have found that the $sWhere only activates when a search field is populated!  I need it to run on the data when it is initially pulled out and then still be active even when the search field is populated.  What I have below is the SELECT query where a new $sQuery can be defined.  I just need help to construct it to make sure it only pulls data WHERE fieldname IS NOT NULL.  I have tried the obvious things with no luck. I am probably missing something fairly obvious.  Thanks again for any help!!

```
/*
     * SQL queries
     * Get data to display
     */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode("`, `", $aColumns))."`
        FROM   $sTable
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
        ";
    $rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());

    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
    $aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT COUNT(`".$sIndexColumn."`)
        FROM   $sTable
    ";
    $rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
    $aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];


    /*
     * Output
     */
    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );

    while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
            {
                /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
            else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
            {
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this should be the final answer (me hopes:-))

**Nah, another update:**

```
$sWhere = "";
if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
{
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {

        $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ') AND active IS NOT NULL';
}

/* Individual column filtering */
for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
{
    if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
    {
        if ( $sWhere == "" )
        {
            $sWhere = "WHERE ";
        }
        else
        {
            $sWhere .= " AND ";
        }

        $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
    }
}
if ( $sWhere != "" )
{
    $sWhere .= " AND active IS NOT NULL ";
}else{
    $sWhere = " WHERE active IS NOT NULL ";
}
```

Note  that two things have changed:

The first query generator is for fulltext search over all fields, so it encapsulates the query in brackets and separates fields with an `OR`.

I added line 11: `$sWhere .= ') AND active IS NOT NULL';`

The second query generator is for individual column filtering which adds an `LIKE` clause to each of the specified columns. This where clause can be empty, so we need to check this before concatenating more parameters.

**Updated:**
I added line 31-36:

```
if ( $sWhere != "" )
{
    $sWhere .= " AND active IS NOT NULL ";
}else{
    $sWhere = " WHERE active IS NOT NULL ";
}
```

**Now, with this update no rows with `active is NULL` will be displayed anymore. No matter if if you do a fulltext search, individual column filtering or just init the table. Maybe you should check if the total count is displayed correct. Are we there yet???**

What you need to do know is to replace the `active` db-field with the one you want to ignore (Carers_Mod_Date) if it's NULL. You can add more excludes in these two lines separated with an `AND`.

Last tips: Always use some spaces around your concatenations because mysql will not mind to much spaces, but missing ones may produce an error.

Comment: Hi!  Thanks again for the help I really do appreciate it.  Unfortunately it still loads all the records even if the "active" db-field has no value in it.  Maybe if we changes it to IS NOT NULL AND != Empty (i don't know the exact syntax) That might do it?!

Comment: The field is a TIMESTAMP field and has been added recently so only the most recent data will have it.  All the existing data will not.  Hope that bit of info helps.  It would be helpful if I wasn't so rubbish at SQL! haha!

Comment: No, EMPTY is not a MySQL keyword. Check for IS NOT NULL AND != ''  Do yourself a favor and install something like phpMyAdmin. It will help you to find out what#s really in your database.

Comment: Sorry ignore my previous BS. You should use AND (active != '' OR active IS NOT NULL) to consider both NULL and empty fields. I'm starting to get confused myself.

Comment: Thanks.  I have that setup and looked to see and it shows NULL in that field.  No idea why it isn't working.  That code you posted looks like it should do it.  So frustrating!

Comment: Hihi, changed my last comment again to AND (active != '' OR active IS NOT NULL). Wish I could see some of your db.

Comment: This is the link to the full code for the datatables querying http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html.  Me too!! Would make it much easier!!  Unfortunately the db is populated with clients data so I cannot give access to anyone!  I have pasted below the table structure for that field.     Name = Carers_Mod_Date  Type=timestamp  Allow Null=Yes  Default=NULL

Comment: Does not help me. And of course you should not give access to a stranger. Last thoughts before I go home for today: You replaced active with Carers_Mod_Date? And: timestamps can default to '0000-00-00 00:00:00' too. Please try this. I wish you could luck on this evening. I'll sure come back to your issue tomorrow.

Comment: I sure did.  I have looked in the contents and they are all populated with NULL.  I will keep trying and let you know if I come up with anything!  Thanks again for all your help!  I hope you have a good evening!

Comment: OK I HAVE PROGRESS!!  This code actually targets the search field on the page and NOT the original datatable data!  I am looking for the code now and will update my question!  This time with your help I should get it working!!!

Comment: Now I begin to understand. You want to ignore NULL fields in Carers_Mod_Date at all, not only in filtering. Try the update to the update of the updated answer:-) I hope they don't throw us out of here. Btw: Could there be a typo in Carers_Mod_Date?

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you @mainguy!  That has done the trick!!!  If you are not bored of me I have 1 more here! haha! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22823408/sql-and-datatables-returning-values-for-the-database I really appreciate your help and patience with me to fix this issue!!

Comment: Already done that. Haha, i'm glad we made it! This is surely a long and confusing thread. But it was big fun to fix that:-)

Comment: Just seen it!! Thanks, I have commented!  It is long and confusing! Haha, glad it was fun for you!!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$sWhere .= " (`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' AND `".$aColumns[$i]."`IS NOT NULL) ";
```

Also quickly made up from my Head. I'll recheck as soon as i find some old project i can modify.

Update: checked it. Works with indvidual column filtering!

Next Update:

Add something like this to your code, just before you encode your result:

```
$output['WHERE'] = $sWhere;
echo json_encode( $output );
```

Now , when you type in a searchterm, you can use the firebug (or else) console to see the response from your server and have the generated WHERE part of your query:

[image: Firebug console example]

Hope this helps you to get along.

Comment: Hmm, second thought: It does not make sense too look if an individual field contains search text or is not null, because a field can either contain searchable text or null and will not be searched anyhow if it's null. So to refine my Answer: Do you want to check if any field in the row is null or a specific field in the row is null? I'll leave my probably useless answer online cause it might help you find out more.

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for your reply!  I need to find if the specific field is NULL. Your code is good and well help me with another element though so it is not useless!  It will not work to only find if a single field "fieldname" is null.  Do you know how that can be done?  Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry that I still don't get it and have to ask again. You want to do something like: SELECT * FROM DB WHERE name LIKE %searchterm% AND company LIKE %searchterm% AND active IS NOT NULL.  Where active is the specific field in your database? I'll update my answer in a minute to show what helped me debugging these querys.

Comment: I added a new answer which should resolve the issue. I leave the old answer in because of my awesome debugging hint:-)

Answer (score 0):

Try appending

```
if ($sWhere == "")
{
    $sWhere = "WHERE";
} else {
    $sWhere .= " AND"
}
$sWhere .= " fieldname IS NOT NULL";
```

after the last line of your existing code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I tried adding it but get a JSON data error.

Comment: Try the revised code.  That is what I get for typing answers from my head... Let me know if that takes care of it.

Comment: Also, I am assuming that fieldname is the actual name of a column in the database.  Is that correct?

Comment: Hi!  No worries!  I have tried the revised version but it still pulls all the data through.  That's right, the fieldname relates to the column in the db.  I have also added a ; after AND with no joy.  Thanks again for your help!